# python waveform to WAV file converter

Tags: python, wav, waveform

I am looking for a way to convert a waveform that is composed of time on the x axis and amplitude on the y axis into a wav or any other audio file.  Code or a python library is much appreciated

[Here is the waveform that I want to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWdwo.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the standard `wave` library. Here is a function that I use. You can modify it further if you need more channels or a different sample width.

```
import wave
import struct

def signal_to_wav(signal, fname, Fs):
    """Convert a numpy array into a wav file.

     Args
     ----
     signal : 1-D numpy array
         An array containing the audio signal.
     fname : str
         Name of the audio file where the signal will be saved.
     Fs: int
        Sampling rate of the signal.

    """
    data = struct.pack('<' + ('h'*len(signal)), *signal)
    wav_file = wave.open(fname, 'wb')
    wav_file.setnchannels(1)
    wav_file.setsampwidth(2)
    wav_file.setframerate(Fs)
    wav_file.writeframes(data)
    wav_file.close()
```

Some links to the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

Comment: (str(len(signal)) + 'h') will also work + i think thats more memory efficient.

+ i think you should mention my amplitude he means displacement, as a fixed displacement sound wouldn't sound like anything